# How to convert a codepoint 32bit integer array (UTF-32?) to Windows native string?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, unicode

How can I convert a codepoint 32bit integer array (UTF-32?) to Windows native string? And what is the Windows native string type for handling Unicode on the API level? Can it handle properly the characters beyond 'u65535'?

Comment: It uses utf-16, a variable-length encoding.  Typically LPWCSTR or WCHAR[] in your program.  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for its native string type.  UTF-16 handles codepoints up to `U+10FFFF`, using *surrogate pairs* to encode codepoints above `U+FFFF`.

Windows has no concept of [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), so you would have to either:

1. If you are using C++11 or later, it has native `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` types, and [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) classes for converting data between UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <locale>

   std::u16string Utf32ToUtf16(const u32string &codepoints)
   {
       std::wstring_convert<
           std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>
           char32_t> conv;
       std::string bytes = conv.to_bytes(codepoints);
       return std::u16string(reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(bytes.c_str()), bytes.length() / sizeof(char16_t));
   }
   ```
2. If you are using an earlier C/C++ version, you will have to convert from UTF-32 to UTF-16 manually:

   ```
   // on Windows, wchar_t is 2 bytes, suitable for UTF-16
   std::wstring Utf32ToUtf16(const std::vector<uint32_t> &codepoints)
   {
       std::wstring result;
       int len = 0;

       for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator iter = codepoints.begin(); iter != codepoints.end(); ++iter)
       {
           uint32_t cp = *iter;
           if (cp < 0x10000) {
               ++len;
           }
           else if (cp <= 0x10FFFF) {
               len += 2;
           }
           else {
               // invalid code_point, do something !
               ++len;
           }
       }

       if (len > 0)
       {
           result.resize(len);
           len = 0;

           for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator iter = codepoints.begin(); iter != codepoints.end(); ++iter)
           {
               uint32_t cp = *iter;
               if (cp < 0x10000) {
                   result[len++] = static_cast<wchar_t>(cp);
               }
               else if (cp <= 0x10FFFF) {
                   cp -= 0x10000;
                   result[len++] = static_cast<wchar_t>((cp >> 10) + 0xD800);
                   result[len++] = static_cast<wchar_t>((cp & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00);
               }
               else {
                   result[len++] = static_cast<wchar_t>(0xFFFD);
               }
           }
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```
3. use a 3rd party library such as [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).